# Contents of file 1.txt between specific word in tag of file 2 in batch/powershell

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have two files, the first contains a list with names:

```
"Dagger Alley 1"
"Steel Home"
"Iron Alley 1"
"Iron Alley 2"
"Swamp Watch"
"Salvation Street 2"
"Salvation Street 3"
"Silver Street 3"
"Golden Axe Guildhall"
```

The second one contains another list:

```
<house name="" houseid="2" entryx="0" entryy="0" entryz="0" rent="0" townid="0" size="93" />
<house name="" houseid="4" entryx="0" entryy="0" entryz="0" rent="0" townid="0" size="68" />
<house name="" houseid="5" entryx="0" entryy="0" entryz="0" rent="0" townid="0" size="94" />
<house name="" houseid="6" entryx="0" entryy="0" entryz="0" rent="0" townid="0" size="133" />
<house name="" houseid="7" entryx="0" entryy="0" entryz="0" rent="0" townid="0" size="73" />
<house name="" houseid="8" entryx="0" entryy="0" entryz="0" rent="0" townid="0" size="101" />
```

How can I insert the entries from file 1 into the `name` field in file 2 like this:

```
<house name="Dagger Alley 1" houseid="2" entryx="0" entryy="0" entryz="0" rent="0" townid="0" size="93" />
```

Comment: how do you know which belongs together? there are more lines in file1 than file2

Comment: You have 9 house names but only 6 xml placeholders. What would the expected output be?

Comment: On top of the other concerns is there something you have tried to get this to work that we can guide you on?

Comment: This list is only a part of rest, every house name from list 1 are sorted and ready to take them line by line to second file.
The schema looks like

`HOUSE_NAME
->  GET_LINE_a
->PUT_AFTER_TAG_IN_LINE_a_IN_FILE_2)`

Where tag is `name=`

I have script to remove a quotes so it can be `name="`

Comment: Are there any usefull links, with simmilar problem? I spend few hours to searching a internet for answer, And i dont know how can i build a sentence to search for, cause my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following should get you started

```
$housenames = @("Dagger Alley 1"
"Steel Home"
"Iron Alley 1"
"Iron Alley 2"
"Swamp Watch"
"Salvation Street 2"
)

$xmlTemplate = @(
'<house name="" houseid="2" entryx="0" entryy="0" entryz="0" rent="0" townid="0" size="93" />'
'<house name="" houseid="4" entryx="0" entryy="0" entryz="0" rent="0" townid="0" size="68" />'
'<house name="" houseid="5" entryx="0" entryy="0" entryz="0" rent="0" townid="0" size="94" />'
'<house name="" houseid="6" entryx="0" entryy="0" entryz="0" rent="0" townid="0" size="133" />'
'<house name="" houseid="7" entryx="0" entryy="0" entryz="0" rent="0" townid="0" size="73" />'
'<house name="" houseid="8" entryx="0" entryy="0" entryz="0" rent="0" townid="0" size="101" />'
)

for ($i=0;$i -lt $housenames.Count; $i++) {    
    $xmlTemplate[$i] -replace '<house name=""', "<house name=""$($housenames[$i])"""
}
```

Comment: THANKS this script works perectly! Powershell is in fact powerfull.

Comment: You are welcome. There's room for improvement but this script get's the job done.

Comment: This method does _not_ process "Contents of file 1.txt" nor "in tag of file 2" as requested. It requires to modify the PS program each time that the data files change.

Comment: @Aacini - True, OP can not copy paste this code. He needs to read/write to the files he needs. I assumed *(correctly it seems)* that he had no problems figuring that out for himself. Besides, SO is not a copy writing service.